# Vagrant Failed to Build Gem Native Extension

Tags: ruby, vagrant, osx-elcapitan

I'm running Vagrant 1.8.1 on OSX 10.11.3 and I'm trying to install a plugin. While attempting to install I get the following the error:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt
............

An error occurred while installing ruby-libvirt (0.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ruby-libvirt -v '0.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.

.........
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

ruby-livirt 0.6.0 has already been installed:

```
# gem list | grep ruby-libvirt
# ruby-libvirt (0.6.0)
```

**Can I bypass this error since the gem is already installed?**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while installing `vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt` it turned out that I was missing some libraries.

After installing below libraries on Ubuntu 16.04 I was able successfully install `vagrant-libvirt` plugin with `vagrant plugin install` command.

- bridge-utils
- build-dep
- dnsmasq-base
- ebtables
- libguestfs-tools
- libvirt-bin
- libvirt-dev
- libxml2-dev
- libxslt-dev
- qemu
- qemu-kvm
- ruby-dev
- ruby-libvirt
- virt-top
- virtinst zlib1g-dev

Depends on your Linux distribution you might look at this [link](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt) to find matching libraries.